# Packages incompatible with tensorflow and keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, object-detection

I am running mask-rcnn github repository , I have installed the packages as per his repository requirements but if I import keras , it gives me error. My installed packages on the notebook are shown below:

```
ipykernel==5.5.3
ipyparallel==6.3.0
ipython==7.16.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==6.0.0
jedi==0.18.0
Jinja2==2.10
joblib==1.0.1
jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2
Keras==2.2.5
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
keras-nightly==2.5.0.dev2021032900
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
keyring==10.6.0
keyrings.alt==3.0
opencv-python==4.5.2.54
Pillow==8.2.0
prometheus-client==0.11.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.18
protobuf==3.17.2
ptyprocess==0.7.0
system-service==0.3
systemd-python==234
tensorboard==2.5.0
tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.0
tensorflow==2.5.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.5.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.10.0
```

Code:

```
import keras 
keras.__version__
```

Output:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'tf2'
```

Mask RCNN Repository link

```
https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN
```

Comment: Mask-RCNN supports tf < 2, but there is some unofficial support but for tf 2.2 or something.

Comment: It is very likely that the package does not support TensorFlow 2.5.

Comment: I have tried many versions , can you please suggest that which version should I move on

Comment: Recently `colab` was upgraded to `TF 2.5.0`, forcing an upgrade to `keras-nightly 2.5.0.dev2021032900`.The recent change affecting you is the install of `keras-nightly`, which is incompatible with `!pip install` of non-nightly keras. Adding `!pip uninstall keras-nightly` before `import keras` will resolve this issue. For more information you can refer [this](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2044#issuecomment-849161550). Thanks!